# how to create window in an application that started as console one?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, window

I know the way window is created when the app is windowed one from the start, that is you call

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE,LPSTR,int nCmdShow);
```

But what to do if I want to get user an option to display a console application output when it ends. That is display its data in more readable form in ad-hoc created window instead of text-only mode that console permits.

In console app I have a function that watches for user key press, and when my program ends it shows message: `press D to display result in a window instead of console`, and in code:

```
if (virtual_key == 0x44) {
  HWND myWindow = myCreateWindFunc(/* data */);
}
```

That is I need to pack all the code for creating window into one function an then just call function on it with the data to fill it's controlls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A console application can create child windows or dialog boxes using any related WinAPI function (`MessageBox`, `DialogBox` etc).

The only caveat is that the create function may require the handle of the console window. To obtain it, you could use the example here [How To Obtain a Console Window Handle](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/124103)