# Create a Window in a Visual Studio 2012 console application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, console-application

Is there a way to create a Window in a C++ Console Application? I have already a console application for creating some data and I want to show them in some graphics, but not inside the console. Is this possible?

Comment: Even a console application have access to the [complete WIN32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including the [windowing system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create window in an application that started as console one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684185/how-to-create-window-in-an-application-that-started-as-console-one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use a function called CreateWindowEx(), See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It's rather complex, you need to create a WNDCLASSEX structure and use RegisterClassEx() on it before passing it as a parameter to CreateWindowEx(). You also need to create  Message Procedure function.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article on MSDN runs through it quite nicely

Comment: A little bit simpler would be to add a resource file to your project, along with a dialog resource, and then call the `CreateDialog` function. That at least avoids having to lay out all of the controls yourself. If you were OK with a modal dialog, you could even call `DialogBox`, which avoids having to implement the message loop yourself.

Comment: @joelyboy, could this be done without wWinMain? cause in the link it says "hInstance is the handle to the application instance. Get this value from the hInstance parameter of wWinMain."

Comment: Yes, you are correct for wWinMain or WinMain, but the hInstance is just the instance of the program which can be obtained by calling    
    GetModuleHandle(0).